# How to do Singular Value Decomposition SVD in Java

Tags: java, android, eclipse

How to find a svd of Matlab in Java.

In Matlab it can be done like this:

`[u,s,v]=svd(X);    %  X is a metric size kxk.`

How can we find u s v  in java?

Comment: for singular value decomposition try to use JAMA ...

Comment: Just keep using Matlab if you want to do linear algebra in a flexible framework ^^